# How to auto-update the slug field in Django admin site?

Tags: django, slug

I know how to auto-populate the slug field of my Blog application from post's title, and it works fine.

But if I edit the title the slug field is not changing.

Is there any way to have it updated automatically?

I use Django's admin site.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from django.utils.text import slugify    
class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug_category = models.SlugField(default='',editable=False, null=True,blank=True,max_length=250)  

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" %(self.category_name)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        value = self.category_name[0:250]
        self.slug_category = slugify(value, allow_unicode=True)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

May be this is usefull..

Comment: Thanks a lot. While this is not auto-updating the slug filed, it does work after saving the changes. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

@Omid Shojaee- Have a look at the following code. You can use the prepopulated_fields

```
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        "id",
        "name",
        "slug",
        "is_active",
    )
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("name",)}
```

Comment: This code - as I said in my question - auto-populates the slug field for NEW posts, not when i EDIT the title.